# Is $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$ defined at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

We know that $\frac{x}{x}=1$ for any nonzero value
$x$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x}=1$; however, I'm wondering that is this function actually defined at $x=0$? Since when $x=0$, this function will become $\frac{0}{0}$, which is undefined.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-0-0-Is-it-equal-to-1

Comment: "which can be any value." -- No, $0/0$ is simply undefined.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Oh right! Thanks, I will revise this statement.

Comment: "*We know that $\frac{x}{x}=1$*" --for any nonzero value $x$--

Comment: When one writes the symbol $\frac ab$, which is a shorthand for $ab^{-1}$, it is assumed that $b \neq 0$, since $0$ is the unique real number that has no multiplicative inverse (this is because $0a = 0$ for any real number $a$). You should revisit the definition of an algebraic field.

Comment: See https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10315/is-simplifying-a-rational-function-considered-as-a-continuous-extension

Comment: Re: "You should revisit the definition of an algebraic field." I think it's quite likely that OP has never heard of fields. This is a common question for a beginning calculus student to ask, and in any case it's not necessary to understand fields in general to answer this question about division of real numbers in particular.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer : In a sense, it is correct that $0/0$ could be "any value" (see my answer). That's why it can't be defined -- it must exist *uniquely*. $1/0$ and $0/0$ are undefined for different reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, $x/x$ is not defined at $0$. Everywhere besides $0$, it is equal to $1$, but at $0$, it is undefined. This is no problem when we consider the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} (x/x)$, because this function is defined everywhere else besides $0$ (and the limit of a function as $x \to 0$ only depends on the values of the function at points besides $0$).
2. It is incorrect to say that $0/0$ can be any value. Instead, $0/0$ does not have any value at all, in other words, it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $a/b$ is defined to be the *unique* number with the property that $b\cdot (a/b) = a$.

For any nonzero real $a$, the symbol $a/0$ can't be uniquely defined because it is impossible to have $0\cdot(a/0)=a$.

But the symbol $0/0$ can't be a uniquely defined for a different reason. Indeed, one could define $0/0 = 0$, since it would be true that $0\cdot (0/0) = 0\cdot (0) =0$. Unfortunately, the same reasoning would apply to saying that $0/0 =\sqrt{\pi}$, since $0\cdot (0/0) = 0\cdot (\sqrt{\pi}) = 0$. So the value does not exist uniquely.